# NPM: npm install hangs on fetchMetaData -> addTmpTa

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I downloaded a `react js` [Github project](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/) and tried `npm install` on this project.
npm install hangs on `fetchMetaData -> addTmpTa`.
My network connectivity is good, tried searching this issue on google but cant find anything. Any help will be highly appreciated. If u know what does `addTmpTa` during the installation please do comment below.

Comment: What `npm` and `node` versions do you use? What OS?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr node v4.4.3, npm v3.8.6, windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to run your npm command from "node.js command prompt", and make sure to run it as administrator.
this has solved my problem;